# dotm file corrupted after unzipping and zipping it

Tags: xml, ms-word

I'm currently working on a dotm file for word. The file already has a ribbon in place where the user can press the icons to perform their desired action. However, I need to add a new button with X functionality. This shouldn't be difficult as it's simple code.

The file gets corrupted in some way during the process. I get the following message when I open it: This document template can not be opened. I narrowed down the problem to the following:

Something is going wrong in the process of: Changing .dotm to .zip -> unzipping file -> zipping file -> changen .zip to .dotm.

When I perform the process above with a working .dotm file, it still gets the message: This document template can not be opened.

I narrowed it down even further by just changing the .dotm from zip and back which didnt result in any issue. So it must be going wrong with zipping/unzipping.

I have tried WinZip and WinRAR but get the same issue with both. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make changes to a dotm file:

1. write .zip instead of .dotm.
2. unzip the file to show the folders.
3. Make your changes.
4. drag the maps in which you made changes and drop them on the zipped file. So do not zip the whole package again. Just drag and drop the changed maps on the already existing zip file.
5. Change the .zip to .dotm.

This worked for. Hope it can be of any help to others.